# GMIC Python plugin crashing in GIMP

Tags: python, plugins, gimp, gmic

I'm getting a procedure not found error when trying to call gimp_freaky_bw "from gimpfu" pdb.plug_in_gmic. This worked with an earlier installation of GIMP. I have just installed GIMP 2.8.22 and G'MIC 2.1.1. The error is:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\32\lib\gimp\2.0\python\gimpfu.py", line 736, in response
    dialog.res = run_script(params)
  File "C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\32\lib\gimp\2.0\python\gimpfu.py", line 361, in run_script
    return apply(function, params)
  File "C:\Users\tommy\.gimp-2.8\plug-ins\DIEGO_ARTISTIC_JamackSketch.py", line 124, in JamackSketch
    pdb.plug_in_gmic(newImage, FreakyBW, 1,    # 1=input only active layer
error: procedure not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent versions of the GMIC plugin the entry point is:

```
pdb.plug_in_gmic_qt(image, drawable, input, output, command)
```

and not `plug_in_gmic` as in the reported error. So, fix the python script, or contact the author to get it fixed.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much. I had to add an output parameter so thanks again for including the parameters in the answer as well. This did it: pdb.plug_in_gmic_qt(newImage, FreakyBW, 1, 1, "-v - -gimp_freaky_bw 90,20,0,0,0,0")